# Playing MP3 files using pure Java

Tags: java, audio, mp3, javasound

Is it possible at all to play MP3 files using only the built-in libraries provided with JDK. I've heard of the **javax.media** library which is found is 1.7 I think. By the way I know of **jlayer** but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Yes. See the 'Service Provider Interface' & 'MP3 decoding support' sections of the [Java Sound Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can play MP3 file, but you need to download MP3 plugin because java framework only supports WAV and AIFF files.

Check http://www.morgenstille.at/blog/how-to-play-a-mp3-file-in-java-simple-and-beautiful/